# Asigning an anonymous function to CLICK event

Tags: javascript, closures, youtube-api, anonymous-function

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JeMz5/)**
If user clicks red arrow i want get skipped to related video.
There are original playlist render function on below which is different from function in demo. Simplest way of modifying original function replacing `img.src=` value with my red arrow url. But it is not smartest way due to the arrow image is not dynamically changing. So, how can i make users skip to related videos by clicking red arrow?

```
 function ytplayer_render_playlist( )
  {
    for ( var i = 0; i < ytplayer_playlist.length; i++ )
    {
      var img = document.createElement( "img" );
      img.src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ytplayer_playlist[ i ] + "/default.jpg";
      var a = document.createElement( "a" );
      a.href = "#ytplayer";

      a.onclick = (
        function( j )
        {
          return function( )
          {
            ytplayer_playitem = j;
            ytplayer_playlazy( 1000 );
          };
        }
      )( i );
      a.appendChild( img );
      document.getElementById( "ytplayer_div2" ).appendChild( a );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing your value j through to the the next function.

```
  a.onclick = (
    function( j )
    {
      return function( j )
      {
        ytplayer_playitem = j;
        ytplayer_playlazy( 1000 );
      };
    }
  )( i );
```

But, I can't see a good reason for that second function and the (i); at the end might need trimming, I don't thinks its doing anything.

```
 a.onclick = (
    function( j )
    {
        ytplayer_playitem = j;
        ytplayer_playlazy( 1000 );
    }
  );
```

Comment: j should be available in the scope.  and wrapping the function to be returned in another function protects and sanitizes the local symbol table so it's a clean reference upon return to each call...

Comment: the trailing `( i )` passes the parameter to the anon that creates the desired anon...

Comment: your second comment sounds interesting, have you got a terminology I can google or a link I can check out? cheers

Comment: I don't know what it's called.  But, the value assigned to a.onclick is an anonymous function with the parameter (i)... the i paramater will be copied to the local symbol table when the function is created and the anonymous within will have a reference to the symbol in the parent state which is different than the next time the anon is called... maybe check out Symbol Tables in compiler theory.

Comment: Ah... the second comment... a common implementation of that is wrapping jquery so that it will work with noconflict active... `(function($) { /* some code that uses $ */ })(jQuery)` passes jquery to the anonymous function in the variable $ which is used within the function